# Virtual keyboard breaks position:fixed elements in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, css, safari, web-inspector

Tested with both Safari and Chrome on iPhone 6 Plus in iOS 11. I have a comment dock panel with the following HTML structure and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="highlighter-docked-panel shown">
    <div class="highlighter-docked-header">Add Comment</div>
    <div class="highlighter-comments-user">...user inner html...</div>
    <div class="highlighter-comment">
        <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">...comment form html...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-confirm confirm-no">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.highlighter-docked-panel {
    right: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 85px;
    z-index: 999999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
}
.highlighter-docked-panel.shown {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The panel is a direct child of the body tag and is not nested within any other html elements. I'm using Web Inspector to debug this from Safari on my desktop with my iPhone connected, so that I can inspect the DOM and see what the browser sees.

As you can see from the following screenshots, when I open the virtual keyboard, the comment dock panel moves up, which is to be expected. However I can't interact with it like I should be able to (e.g. I can't click into the textarea again or the RESPOND or CANCEL buttons), so I used the Inspect Element to highlighted the dock, and it appears the positioning doesn't match up. With the virtual keyboard shown, the browser doesn't see that the fixed dock has actually moved up, as is evident when I select the panel in the inspector.

Panel positioning before keyboard is shown (disregard the highlight text handles - those are under the fixed dock panel):

[image]

Panel positioning after keyboard is shown:

[image]

Why would the browser show the panel in a different position visually than where it really thinks it is? Is there a way to "refresh" the fixed panels after the keyboard is shown?

This also happens with other position:fixed elements that I have such as a login form that overlays the entire page.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? Run into the same issue now.

Answer (score -1):

This is the expected behavior.  When the keyboard is opened, it does not overlay the browser's view port.  It shrinks the view port to make room for the keyboard.  Your comments panel is still positioned 85px from the bottom of the newly shrunken view port.  You may want to try putting the comment panel inside the container that the text is in.  Then make that containers `position: relative` and the highlighter-docked-panel `position: absolute`.  If I understand your question correctly, that should be the look you are going for.

Edit: although in that scenario, the user won't be able to see what they are typing.

Comment: Why isn't this reflected in the web inspector then? I guess that's what's throwing me off. If the browser moves the panel up visually, why doesn't it do so in the DOM? Doesn't seem right to show something were it doesn't actually exist...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The comment panel has position: fixed and bottom:85px.  So the bottom of the panel it should always be 85 pixels above the bottom of the view port, which is what I see in both screenshots.  Unless I am completely misunderstanding something.

Comment: Nothing about those two css properties would ever move its position in the html.  In fact css can not move elements in the html, just where they appear on the screen.  Two totally different things

Comment: In the second screenshot, the comment panel is 85px above the keyboard, not the viewport.

Comment: The top of the keyboard **is** the bottom of the viewport.  That's what I am saying in the answer.  The keyboard is NOT part of (or inside) the viewport of the **browser**.  Viewport of the browser and the screen of the phone are two different things.

Comment: Not according to the second screenshot. Look at the blue shaded area. Notice how it's still down hidden under the keyboard, still 85px from the bottom edge of the viewport prior to the keyboard opening (despite the browser visually showing it 85px from the top of the keyboard). It is precisely this discrepancy that is causing the issue. Perhaps you're not looking at the screenshot correctly... that blue shaded area was not added by me - that's what the browser displays when you click the element in the inspector.

Comment: Sorry you're not getting it, I can't explain it any better.

Comment: sn3ll don't you see the blue overlay? If it was correct, its bottom would be at the top of the keyboard. Instead 1. It's under the keyboard 2. it is not overlaying the actual DOM element it's supposed to show. I'm facing the same bug, it's filed in webkit trac here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192564 seems corrected, but not yet released.